# 'NoneType' object is not iterable while using itertools.chain.from_iterable

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql

I generate a list of list of strings using the following line in spark

```
l = text.map(lambda x: tokenize(x[0])).collect()
```

Output of l looks like this (subset of a long list):

```
[['@always_nidhi'], ['@always_nidhi', '@OnlyDancers', '@IcelandNatural'], ['@always_nidhi', '@OnlyDancers', '@IcelandNatural']]
```

It's a list of list of string values. I want a unique set of names and hence my first step is am merging it using the following line. (later I'll use set to get unique values)

```
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(l))
```

But I get this error

**'NoneType' object is not iterable**

Can someone please help.

Comment: Could you post more code? That error suggests that your list `l` is equivalent to `None`. Leading me to believe there's something else going on in your source.

Comment: [Catch the excetion](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and print ```l``` - is there anything in it?

Comment: From the answers I reached the solution that my prior code has some mistake which is giving this error. I am debugging that part now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not able to replicate your error, the following works on Python 2.7.

```
>>> print set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(l))
set(['@OnlyDancers', '@always_nidhi', '@IcelandNatural'])
```

However you could use the following generator. It's functionally equivalent to `chain()`.

```
>>> print set(inner for sub_list in l for inner in sub_list)
set(['@OnlyDancers', '@always_nidhi', '@IcelandNatural'])
```

Comment: From the answers I reached the solution that my prior code has some mistake which is giving this error. I am debugging that part now